# Use Excel "auto correct option"

Tags: vba, excel

I'm Korean, I'm using Korean Excel.

The Excel supports option for us to correct wrong typed word in other language

for example,

when we're typing korean word '사랑',
but if we have mistake to type 'tkfkd' in Engish mode and Press Enter key,
It change the word to original korean mode '사랑'

So I want to use this skill for many datas by VBA

I wrote below code.

row (tkfkd,러브,사랑,etc...)

i expect the word ("tkfkd") will be changed to ("사랑") 
But There are no changes of that word ("tkfkd")

How can i use this "auto-correcting word" otion in VBA?

please let me know.

Thanks you.

```
for row 0 to lastrow
    Cells(row, 11 + i).Select
    Application.SendKeys "+{F2}"
    Application.SendKeys "+{ENTER}" next row
```

Comment: It s not clear to me if you are talking about using the Autocorrect to correct words inside your code or if you want to launch Autocorrect from VBA to correct something from a sheet (row 0 to lastrow)
And what does this all to do with the code you wrote?

Answer (score 1):

```
For row=1 to lastrow
     If cells(row, 11+i)="tkfkd" then cells(row,11+i)= _
              Range("D1").Value   'D1 contain 사랑 text
     End if
Next
```

Comment: gets rid of the select ... +1.

Comment: i intend to correct the word without any extra DB Souces('D1 contain 사랑 text), I guess It could be possible when i use a Auto Correct option in excel, so i ask